# pythonic way to vectorize ifelse over list

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic way to reverse the elements of one list based on another equally-sized list?

```
lista = [1,2,4]
listb = ['yes', 'no', 'yep']

# expecting [-1, 2,-4]

[[-x if y in ['yes','yep'] else x for x in lista] for y in listb]
# yields [[-1, -2, -4], [1, 2, 4], [-1, -2, -4]]
```

if `listb[i]` is `yes` or `yep`, `result[i]` should be the opposite of `lista`.

Maybe a lambda function applied in list comprehension?

Comment: Try iterating over both lists at once using `... for x, y in zip(lista, listb)`.

Comment: cheers, mate. don't hesitate to post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `zip`?

```py
>>> [-a if b in ('yes','yep') else a for a,b in zip(lista, listb)]
[-1, 2, -4]
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, using tuple indices with `zip`:

```
[(x,-x)[y in ('yes','yep')] for x,y in zip(lista,listb)] 
# [-1, 2, -4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting solution is using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) and `zip`:

```
import itertools as it    
l = list(it.starmap(lambda x, y: -x if y in ('yes', 'yep') else x, zip(lista, listb)))
print(l)
```

Output: `[-1, 2, -4]`